# Altered One Stored Procedure, Another One Loses Performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This isn't a terribly technical question as I am just looking for theories onto why something like this would happen.

In our application, we have a few different stored procedures that read mostly the same tables. We had been monitoring SQL Server and trying to knock off the most expensive queries on our list (highest I/O, CPU time etc). We have seen quite a lot of gains by altering the SQL and/or altering the application.

Anyway, we altered stored procedure #1 and released it. As expected it performed much better. However stored procedure #2 (which reads similar data) all of sudden saw it's performance metrics decrease (it is consuming much more I/O).

We are still in a better place after the release but I am trying to figure out why this is happening. Thus far, I have been unable to replicate the issue (it is still performing fine for me no matter how I use the stored proc).

Also, the stored proc does not perform poorly every time in production. The majority of the times it is run, it performs just fine.

Any ideas?

We are using SQL Server 2008.  We did not alter any indexes.

Comment: Do the stored procedures contain queries that are similar enough to share the same plan? If you want to see the differences between two queries, capture *actual* execution plans and compare them.

Comment: No, they have different execution plans (and had different execution plans before the change).

Comment: Ok, so did you capture an actual execution plan from the now slower query before it was slow? Have you compared that to the execution plan now? By looking at the execution plan now, we can perhaps tell you why it's slow, but if we have no baseline to compare it to, we can't tell you why it used to be faster. Surely it is just a coincidence that the performance change coincided with the release of the other procedure; perhaps there were other data, stats, plan cache etc. changes in the meantime. Solve the slow query, don't try to correlate it with some other query change.

Answer (score 0):

This may not seem at all related, but humor me and check your *max degree of parallelism* on the database instance:

EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism'

My suspicion is the sporadic poor execution of your SP was always happening, but was being masked by the poor performance of the db in general.  Chances are this config value is set to 0, which is a bad thing by default.  You will want to change this to a value somewhere between 1 and 8 based on a variety of factors you should reference this KB for: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2806535

I have a feeling your getting a runaway parallel query from time to time which would explain the behavior you're seeing, and changing this value will help curb that.

P.S. My apologies for not appending a comment to the question, but my reputation isn't high enough yet...